# Regular Expression Question - Two Negative Look behinds in the same expression

Tags: r, regex, nlp

I have the following problem for which I have been working on for a few hours.
I am trying to build the following RegEx :

I want to be able to extract the word *reduced* from sentences but not if the word is preceded by a negative expression.

For example

```
Sentences                                |Output
1. lv function is reduced                    reduced
2. lv function is not reduced                -
3. reduced lv function                       reduced
4. no evidence of reduced lv function        -
```

Right now, I have been able to a have a function RegEx for in the cases 3 and 4 where the adjective precedes the noun of interest using a negative look behind.

However, for the cases 1 and 2, the negative look behind does not work.

Here are sentences and the current RegEx to test :

```
((?<!((no|not|none)(?:\D*?)))(reduced|depressed|normal)(?:\D*?))?(?:lv function|lv|systolic function|left ventricular ejection fraction)(((?:.*\bnot\b)(\D*))(reduced|depressed|normal))?

Sentences :
lv function is reduced   
lv function is not reduced 
reduced lv function
no evidence of reduced lv function
```

Alternatively here is a link : [regexr.com/4tc61](http://%20regexr.com/4tc61)

Also, I am ultimately going to be working in R.

Thank you all.

Comment: You are making a fundamental error when building a regex: you are trying to write a regex for a JS regex engine, but want to use it in a TRE/PCRE/ICU R regex engines. So, even if it works for you online, it will still not work for you in the end

Comment: What do you mean by `\D*`? What if there are indeed numbers?

Comment: This is not clear, please update the question with exact verbal requirements. It is not clear when the match is to be failed.

Comment: The regex you try to write is something like https://regex101.com/r/11mwnU/2. It is rather unwieldly.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, the ReGex you wrote works perfectly. It's indeed complicated though but it seems to work. \D* [means > 0 non digit character], there should never be numbers in those cases. Indeed, I am working on this platform for JS regex (simply because it's the only one I found) but I'll convert it back to R regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex solution will be very complex, and you may use it only if you understand it well. I will try to explain it as well as I can.

*Q*: **How do I match something that is not preceded with a string of unknown length if my lookbehinds do not support such patterns?**
*A*: **Match what you do not need, skip the matched texts, and go on matching from the position where the match failed**.

You may do it with PCRE regex that supports `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` (or shorter `(*SKIP)(*F)`) construct.

Now, look at the pattern:

```
(?:\b(?:no|not|none)\b\D*?\b(?:reduced|depressed|normal)\b\D*?\b(?:lv function|lv|systolic function|left ventricular ejection fraction)\b|\b(?:lv function|lv|systolic function|left ventricular ejection fraction)\b\D*?\bnot\b\D*?\b(?:reduced|depressed|normal)\b)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:\b(reduced|depressed|normal)\b\D*?)?\b(?:lv function|lv|systolic function|left ventricular ejection fraction)\b(?:\D*?\b(reduced|depressed|normal)\b)?
```

Looks unwieldly, but let's go through the constituents:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group that serves as a container, the `(*SKIP)(*F)` will be applied to all alternatives inside it):

  - `\b(?:no|not|none)\b\D*?\b(?:reduced|depressed|normal)\b\D*?\b(?:lv function|lv|systolic function|left ventricular ejection fraction)\b`:

    - `\b(?:no|not|none)\b` - any of the words inside the non-capturing group as whole words
    - `\D*?` - 0+ non-digit chars
    - `\b(?:reduced|depressed|normal)\b` - any of the words inside the non-capturing group as whole words
    - `\D*?` - 0+ non-digit chars
    - `\b(?:lv function|lv|systolic function|left ventricular ejection fraction)\b` - any of the texts inside the non-capturing group as whole words
  - `|` - or
  - `\b(?:lv function|lv|systolic function|left ventricular ejection fraction)\b\D*?\bnot\b\D*?\b(reduced|depressed|normal)\b`:

    - `\b(?:lv function|lv|systolic function|left ventricular ejection fraction)\b` - any of the texts inside the non-capturing group as whole words
    - `\D*?\bnot\b\D*?` - 0+ non-digits as few as possible, whole word `not`, 0+ non-digits as few as possible
    - `\b(?:reduced|depressed|normal)\b` - any of the texts inside the non-capturing group as whole words
- `)(*SKIP)(*F)` - end of the container group, and the PCRE verbs that fail the match, making the regex engine go on to search for matches starting at the position where the match failed
- `|` - or (that is, now, really match what we need with the next alternative)
- `(?:\b(reduced|depressed|normal)\b\D*?)?\b(?:lv function|lv|systolic function|left ventricular ejection fraction)\b(?:\D*?\b(reduced|depressed|normal)\b)?`:

  - `(?:\b(reduced|depressed|normal)\b\D*?)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching a `reduced`, `depressed` or `normal` **captured into Group 1** (we need to extract the word matched with this group!) as whole words and then any 0+ non-digit chars as few as possible
  - `\b(?:lv function|lv|systolic function|left ventricular ejection fraction)\b` - any of the texts inside the non-capturing group as whole words
  - `(?:\D*?\b(reduced|depressed|normal)\b)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching any 0+ non-digit chars as few as possible and then captures into Group 2 a `reduced`, `depressed` or `normal` **captured into Group 1** as a whole word.

There are so many repetitive parts, so it makes sense to use variables in the pattern:

```
x <- c("lv function is reduced", "lv function is not reduced", "reduced lv function", "no evidence of reduced lv function")

cap <- "reduced|depressed|normal"
negate_prefix <- paste0("(?:\\b(?:no|not|none)\\b\\D*?\\b(?:",cap,")\\b\\D*?")
match <- "\\b(?:lv function|lv|systolic function|left ventricular ejection fraction)\\b"
regex <- paste0(negate_prefix,
   match, "|", match, "\\D*?\\bnot\\b\\D*?\\b(?:",cap,")\\b)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:\\b(",cap,")\\b\\D*?)?",match,"(?:\\D*?\\b(",cap,")\\b)?")
```

So, all we need is the *captured substrings*. See [the R demo online](https://ideone.com/UWLJ2s):

```
results <- regmatches(x, regexec(regex, x, perl=TRUE))
unlist(lapply(results, function(x) paste(x[-1], collapse="")))
## => [1] "reduced" ""        "reduced" ""
```

Comment: @EricYamga One thing I did not mention: the code I sypplied will work only if there is `reduced`, `depressed` or `normal` on only one side of the key phrases. The `paste` is joining the groups into one string assuming only one group contains some text. If you need to handle the cases when both groups are not empty, please let know.

Comment: No that will work. It will only be on one side! Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @Wiktor Stribiżew have reached a problem. The RegEx worked well for the most part but for this sentence : "There is mild concentric left ventricular hypertrophy. The visually estimated left ventricular ejection fraction is normal at 65%. There are no regional wall motion abnormalities. Doppler parameters are consistent with reduced systolic function.  The regex does not match the sentence". Here is the demo again : https://regexr.com/4tt3b. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if the example is as complicated as it gets, then something like this might work?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame(sent = c("lv function is reduced",
                             "lv function is not reduced",
                             "reduced lv function",
                             "no evidence of reduced lv function"))
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(out_test = +str_detect(sent, "not|no"),
         output = ifelse(out_test == 0, "reduced", NA)) %>% 
  select(-out_test)
df
                                sent  output
1             lv function is reduced reduced
2         lv function is not reduced    <NA>
3                reduced lv function reduced
4 no evidence of reduced lv function    <NA>
```